# How to send a linux log file directly to S3 (thus bypassing CloudWatch)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

How to send a linux log file directly to S3 (thus bypassing CloudWatch).

One example, is using logrotate as describe in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-logrotate-and-s3cmd-to-archive-logs-to-object-storage-on-ubuntu-16-04. Are there better techniques now available? I've confirmed you cannot configure the CloudWatch agent to send to S3 instead of CloudWatch.

Answer (score 1):

Which kind of logs that you want to upload to S3?

I guess that you want to ignore Amazon CloudWatch and directly upload to Amazon S3 bucket.

1. Then, you just need to write a **custom script** (Bash/Python or
   anything else) to retrieve your Linux Logs. For example, I would like to retrieve memory usage as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

MEMORY=$(free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf "%.2f\t", $3*100/$2 }')
echo $MEMORY > MEM.log.$(date +"%d-%m-%y")
```

2. After that, try to generate and use IAM secret key-pair which can
   communicate to Amazon S3 with sufficient actions (describe/upload).

```
aws configure
```

3. At last, you can use `crontab` or any Linux services to
   automatically trigger objects uploading API command to your Amazon S3
   bucket.

```
crontab -e
```

```
*/5 * * * *    aws cp /home/log/*.log s3://<YOUR-BUCKET>/<YOUR-BUCKET-PATH>/
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your reply.

Firstly I want to export the below logs into s3 bucket directly bypassing cloudwatch.

```
/var/log/audit/audit.log
/var/log/dmesg
/var/log/maillog
/var/log/messages
/var/log/secure
/var/log/lynx/lynx.log
/var/log/lynx/cmx_auth.log
/var/log/lynx/lynxaudit.log
/var/log/lynx/lynxretention.log
/var/log/tomcat/catalina.log
```

while searching for different ways I found some thing like using  s3cmd and exporting the logs into s3 bucket directly. something like below

```
1. yum install s3cmd
2. sudo s3cmd --configure --config=/root/logrotate-s3cmd.config (Where it asks the below information)
   Access Key: your-access-key
   Secret Key: your-secret-key
   Default Region [US]: ENTER
   S3 Endpoint [s3.amazonaws.com]: nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com
   DNS-style bucket+hostname:port template for accessing a bucket [%(bucket)s.s3.amazonaws.com]: %(bucket)s.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com
   Encryption password: ENTER, or specify a password to encrypt
   Path to GPG program [/usr/bin/gpg]: ENTER
   Use HTTPS protocol [Yes]: ENTER
   HTTP Proxy server name: ENTER, or fill out your proxy information
   At this point, s3cmd will summarize your responses, then ask you to test the connection. Press y then ENTER to start the test:

Output
Test access with supplied credentials? [Y/n] y
Please wait, attempting to list all buckets...
Success. Your access key and secret key worked fine :-)

3. Edit vi /etc/logrotate.d/tomcat

/var/log/tomcat/catalina.out {
  copytruncate
  rotate 3
  daily
  missingok
  compress
  create 0644 tomcat tomcat
    dateext
    dateformat -%Y-%m-%d-%s
    lastaction
            HOSTNAME=`hostname`
            /usr/bin/s3cmd sync /var/log/tomcat/catalina.log*.gz "s3://cmx-doc-eu-west-2-arv/$HOSTNAME/"
            /usr/bin/s3cmd sync /var/log/tomcat/catalina.out*.gz "s3://cmx-doc-eu-west-2-arv/$HOSTNAME/tomcat/"
    endscript
}

4. After adding the above I tested immediately whether it is working properly or not.

sudo logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf --verbose --force
```

But the wierd part is step 2 did not worked the logrotate-s3cmd.config file don't have any access keys and secret keys. It just worked like that.